# Native query with named parameter fails with "Not all named parameters have been set"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to execute a simple native query, but it does not work:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;

Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM mytable where username = :username");
em.setProperty("username", "test");
(int) q.getSingleResult();
```

Why am I getting this exception?

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [username]
```

Comment: Just a tip, why do you want use native query for this query? You can do the same using Jpa query language, there a lot of benefits to prefer Jpa query.

Comment: @Rafael Zeffa Could I use jpa without having an `@Entity` class? If so, could you please suggest how to optimize it using jpa?

Comment: you can't do it without a entity, but why you can't map a @entity for that table?

Comment: You call `setProperty`. It should be `setParameter`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47512356/1523648)

Comment: View this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50365522/3073945

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Named parameters are not supported by JPA in native queries, only for JPQL. You must use positional parameters.

> Named parameters follow the rules for identifiers defined in Section 4.4.1. The use of named parameters applies to the Java Persistence query language, and is not defined for native queries. **Only positional parameter binding may be portably used for native queries.**

So, use this

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM mytable where username = ?1");
q.setParameter(1, "test");
```

While JPA specification doesn't support named parameters in native queries, some JPA implementations (like [Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#d0e13930)) may support it

> Native SQL queries support positional as well as named parameters

However, this couples your application to specific JPA implementation, and thus makes it unportable.

Comment: yes but i forgot it ...and test it on my example. please mark this answer as right.

Comment: I know is an old thread, but JPA does allow named parameters, the problem on the original question was this: em.setProperty("username", "test"); and should be like this q.setParameter("username", "test");

Comment: @vicmac Does JPA really allow? I am using it with Hibernate. Positional binding and Named binding with # works but not with colon (:)

Answer (score 19):

You are calling `setProperty` instead of `setParameter`. Change your code to

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM mytable where username = :username");
em.setParameter("username", "test");
(int) q.getSingleResult();
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 18):

After many tries I found that you should use `createNativeQuery` And you can send parameters using `#` replacement

**In my example**

```
String UPDATE_lOGIN_TABLE_QUERY = "UPDATE OMFX.USER_LOGIN SET LOGOUT_TIME = SYSDATE WHERE LOGIN_ID = #loginId AND USER_ID = #userId";


Query query = em.createNativeQuery(logQuery);

            query.setParameter("userId", logDataDto.getUserId());
            query.setParameter("loginId", logDataDto.getLoginId());

            query.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 17):

I use EclipseLink. This JPA allows the following way for the native queries:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable where username = ?username");
q.setParameter("username", "test");
q.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 8):

Use set Parameter from query.

```
Query q = (Query) em.createNativeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM mytable where username = ?1");
q.setParameter(1, "test");
```

Comment: no that is the right import. But you should use integer parameters. NativeQuery doesnt works with string parameters. I edit my answer.

Comment: By the way, you might want to revert your edit. It DOES work with named param (`... username = :username`).

Comment: normally you should get Named parameter "username" is used in native SQL query "SELECT count(*) FROM Persons where username = :username". But named parameter is not allowed in native SQL query, use integer parameter

Comment: @pL4Gu33 Wihle JPA doesn't support this, some implementations do, like Hibernate. That's the reason it works for the OP. I've edited my answer with this info.

Answer (score 6):

This was a bug fixed in version 4.3.11
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2851

**EDIT:**
Best way to execute a native query is still to use **NamedParameterJdbcTemplate**
It allows you need to retrieve a result that is not a managed entity ; you can use a **RowMapper** and even a **Map of named parameters**!

```
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

final List<Long> resultList = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(query, 
            mapOfNamedParamters, 
            new RowMapper<Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            return rs.getLong(1);
        }
    });
```