# How to call firebird selectable stored procedure using JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, stored-procedures, firebird

I'm trying to call a Firebird selectable procedure using JPA. The method looks like:

```
 public void addLineToBrokerReport(Map<String, Object> parametersForAddDealsProc) {

        MapUtils.debugPrint(System.out, "Parameters for procedure", parametersForAddDealsProc);

        String q = "select a.dol as id, a.out$error_code as error_code " +
            "from ADD_LINE (:IN$DOC," +
            ":IN$SHARE, " +
            ":IN$B_ACC, " +
            ":IN$S_ACC, " +
            ":IN$COMMENT) a";

      Query query = em.createNamedQuery(q, CallProcedureResult.class);
       for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parametersForAddDealsProc.entrySet()) {
           query.setParameter("\"" + entry.getKey()+ "\"", entry.getValue());
        }
        CallProcedureResult result = (CallProcedureResult) query.getSingleResult();
        LOG.info("Error_code = " + result.getError_code()  + " dol = " + result.getId());

    }
```

After calling it is return the next error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Named query not found: select
>   a.dol as id, a.out$error_code as error_code from
>   P_TDA_ADD_LINE_TO_BROKER_REP (:IN$DOC,:IN$SHARE, :IN$B_ACC, :IN$S_ACC,
>   :IN$COMMENT) a
>
> at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:665)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.createNamedQuery(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.comp.app.TradesUpload.TradesUpload.addLineToBrokerReport(TradesUpload.java:454)
>     at
>   com.comp.app.TradesUpload.TradesUploadTest.addLineToBrokerReport(TradesUploadTest.java:69)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)    at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
>     at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

- Is it possible to call firebird select procedure using JPA?
- Why "Named query not found" if there is `Query query =
  em.createNamedQuery(q, CallProcedureResult.class);` in method?

Comment: Note that selectable stored procedures behave like a normal select query, so you don't need to handle them like stored procedures; using CallProcedureResult is likely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

`em.createNamedQuery` first argument is supposed to be the NAME of the `NamedQuery` (not the JPQL). The `NamedQuery` itself you would have defined in an annotation or XML, and specified the NAME against it. Also if you mean to invoke SQL direct (rather than JPQL), you need a `NamedNativeQuery` which is for a native query.

JPA 2.1 has support for Stored Procedures; whether that would work for invoking Firebird's things I've no idea, but you could try it also

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to call firebird select procedure using JPA?

Yes it is. You can use `EntityManager#createNativeQuery` instead.

> Why "Named query not found" if there is `Query query =
>   em.createNamedQuery(q, CallProcedureResult.class);` in method?

The first parameter of `EntityManager#createNamedQuery` must be a `NamedQuery` and it is not, it is an actual query in your case.

**Unrelated** to your problem, using named parameters in native queries is supported by Hibernate but it cannot be portably used across JPA implementations (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28829942/5078385).

Comment: If I use `em.createNativeQuery(q, CallProcedureResult.class);` then  `query.setParameter("IN$SHARE", parametersForAddDealsProc.get("IN$SHARE") )` throws `Cannot resolve query parameter 'IN$SHARE' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection checks for the following Persistence model problems:
Named query not found
Query parameter not found`

Comment: This was Idea problem.

Comment: Now i receive in log: `Hibernate: select a.dol as id, a.out$error_code as error_code from ADD_LINE (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) a`. Where are parameters?

Comment: Is your query working then? If that is so, and you want to be able to see your parameters value in the log, maybe you are looking for the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1713464/5078385.