# caused by:sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:user lacks privilege or object not found:FROM_UNIXTIME

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite, hsqldb

SELECT p.patient_id as patientId,p.user_id as userId,u.first_name as first_name

I want this query to run in my junit test case.I know hsql does not support this and i need a solution for this.pls help

Comment: With HSQLDB, use `TIMESTAMP(:startTime / 1000)` instead of `FROM_UNIXTIME(`

Comment: Why `sqlite` tag

Answer (score 1):

This is a MySQL query and therefore if you want to run it as is, it will have to be run as a native query.  You can use code similar to the following:

```
String query = "SELECT p.patient_id as patientId ...";
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query);
List<Object[]> rows = q.getResultList();
for (Object[] r: rows) {
    // process each row as your unit test requires
}
```

If you need to use a parameterized native query, then you will have to use positional parameters.  Refer to the following Stack Overflow question for an example:

[How to create a native query with named parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829818/how-to-create-a-native-query-with-named-parameters)

Comment: em.createNativeQuery(query); what is em ??

Comment: How are you executing your HQL?  I assumed you have an entity manager which you are using to execute your queries.  If you are using raw JDBC let us know and the answer can be updated.