# why can't I use "truncate" in spring boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I wanna use "truncate table" statement instead of "delete" statement in spring boot project cause I need reset the auto increment id in mysql. Here is my code:

```
@PersistenceContext protected EntityManager em;
@Override
  public void removeAllShopeeCategory() {
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("truncate table ShopeeCategoryDto shopeecategory");
    Query q = this.em.createQuery(query.toString());
    q.executeUpdate();
  }
```

but there is an exception like this:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: truncate near line 1, column 1
```

other operation has worked, such as insert, update or select, what's the reason and what should I modify it?

Comment: Your query is a **SQL** query. `createQuery()` expected a **JPQL** query. JPQL and SQL are two different languages. Like C++ and Java. You can't compile a Java program with a C++ compiler. Same here. If you want to execute SQL queries, don't use createQuery(). Use https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-

Comment: what do you mean by that? I used createQuery() for update, select methods, it works

Comment: TRUNCATE is not part of JPQL, you need to use a native query, not a JPQL query

Comment: understood, let me try native query, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 entityManager.createNativeQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE " + tableName + " CASCADE")
            .executeUpdate()
```

Comment: Note this will open you up to SQL injection. *Never* concatenate string to make a SQL query; use parameter binding instead, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28829942/1389817)

Answer (score 1):

Please use https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String- with native sql queries.

Comment: also use the table name and not the entity class name.

Comment: understood, I will try it