# Using BETWEEN in native query in JPQL

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink, java-ee-8

I tried to make a query using `BETWEEN` in JPQL, I already tested it in SQL and it works, but when I implemented in JPQL I got an error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
Incorrect syntax near ':'.
Error Code: 102"
```

I don't understand why there is the error near `:`, can anybody help me figure it out?

Here is my code:

```java
public List<Object[]> reportPendapatan(String tahun) {
    String tahun1 = tahun +"-01-01";
    String tahun2 = tahun +"-12-31";
    return em.createNativeQuery("SELECT p.tanggal, m.nama, pg.nama_jenis, g.nama_guru,pg.harga_masuk FROM Pendaftaran p, Murid m, pengajian pg, Guru g  WHERE p.id_murid = m.id_murid and p.tanggal between :tahun and :tahun2 and p.id_guru = g.id_guru and p.id_jenis = pg.id_jenis and p.status=4")       
            .setParameter("tahun", tahun1)
            .setParameter("tahun2", tahun2)
            .getResultList(); 
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `JSQL`? Do you mean `JPQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42573540/13279831), EclipseLink has slightly different syntax of setting named parameters in native queries using `?` prefix instead of `:`

```java
public List<Object[]> reportPendapatan(String tahun) {
    String tahun1 = tahun +"-01-01";
    String tahun2 = tahun +"-12-31";
    return em.createNativeQuery(
        "SELECT p.tanggal, m.nama, pg.nama_jenis, g.nama_guru,pg.harga_masuk "
        + "FROM Pendaftaran p, Murid m, pengajian pg, Guru g "
        + "WHERE p.id_murid = m.id_murid and p.tanggal between ?tahun and ?tahun2 "
        + "and p.id_guru = g.id_guru and p.id_jenis = pg.id_jenis and p.status=4")
        .setParameter("tahun", tahun1)
        .setParameter("tahun2", tahun2)
        .getResultList(); 
}
```

Other option is to use *positional parameters* 1 and 2 for `tahun1` and `tahun2` respectively:

```java
    // ...
    return em.createNativeQuery(
        "SELECT p.tanggal, m.nama, pg.nama_jenis, g.nama_guru,pg.harga_masuk "
        + "FROM Pendaftaran p, Murid m, pengajian pg, Guru g "
        + "WHERE p.id_murid = m.id_murid and p.tanggal between ? and ? "
        + "and p.id_guru = g.id_guru and p.id_jenis = pg.id_jenis and p.status=4")
        .setParameter(1, tahun1)
        .setParameter(2, tahun2)
        .getResultList();
```