# How can I run this SQL statement with SpringBoot data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to create a data filter using SpringBoot and PostgreSQL, I'm trying to run a query to get a customer by its `name` or `id` or `account id` in a searchBar,  running into an issue when running a native SQL statement in Spring Data JPA, I'm getting the following error:

[image: Trace Error]

The error says that `Could not execute query`. I've tried running the statement in different ways but still giving me the error, these are the ways I have tried:

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT json_data FROM contact WHERE name = :searchText OR account_id = :searchText OR id = :searchText", 
        nativeQuery = true)

@Query(
        value = "SELECT json_data FROM contact WHERE contact.name LIKE %:searchText% OR contact.account_id LIKE %:searchText% OR contact.id LIKE %:searchText%", 
        nativeQuery = true)

@Query(
        value = "SELECT json_data FROM contact WHERE name = ?1 OR account_id = ?1 OR id = ?1", 
        nativeQuery = true)

Page<Contact> findByWord(Pageable pageable, @Param("searchText") String searchText);
```

I'm able to run successfully the query in PGAdmin as follows:

```sql
SELECT json_data FROM contact 
WHERE name = 'TESLA ARQUITECTURA S.A.S' 
OR account_id = '' 
OR id = ''
```

or:

```sql
SELECT json_data FROM contact 
WHERE name = '' 
OR contact.account_id = '' 
OR contact.id = '2'
```

or:

```sql
SELECT json_data FROM contact 
WHERE name = '' 
OR account_id = '1674590687S' 
OR id = ''
```

All of these statements are working and the idea is that if I pass as a parameter to the SQL statement it will return the information from the column `json_data`.

So I'm not sure if im doing something wrong when creating the query in the repository, I would appreciate so much your help on this.

Comment: IIRC, native queries do not support named parameters, only positional parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Native query with named parameter fails with "Not all named parameters have been set"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829818/native-query-with-named-parameter-fails-with-not-all-named-parameters-have-been)

Comment: Hey @Turing85 Oh I didn't know, however I also tried with positional parameters in the following way `SELECT json_data FROM contact WHERE name = ?1 OR account_id = ?1 OR id = ?1` but still giving me exactly the same error `Resolved [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query`. I edited the post and added the method and parameter I'm setting up in the repository layer.

Comment: Have you removed the `@Param` annotation? Can you provide a [MRE], e.g. in form of a git repository?

Comment: Which version of spring data are you using? Also the error `column name seq_id was not found in this result set` is obviously what you should be googling.

Comment: Bang, figured it out, do `select *` not `select json_data`, you are trying to map a single column into a whole Entity.

Comment: You completely right! It just worked out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `select *` not `select json_data` in your query, currently you are trying to map a single column into a whole Entity that's why it's complaining the id is missing from the result set. `column name seq_id was not found in this result set` was there in the error log all along.

Comment: Yeap, you were right sir! Thank you!