# Passing parameter value in native query where it will be surrounded by single quotation marks

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, entitymanager

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to pass a parameter value to a native sql query. The value in the resulted query is surrounded with single quotation marks. That must be the main issue I think.

The following query works if the parameter value is hard-coded. I've excluded unrelated parts from it:

```
var query = 
"""
select
...
and ss.status_date < now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - interval '70' minute
...
""";
```

However when I tried to pass the value:

```
var query = 
"""
select
...
and ss.status_date < now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - interval ':x' minute
...
""";

var searchQuery = em.createNativeQuery(query, BikeEntity.class);
searchQuery.setParameter("x", 70);
```

I got the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [x], expecting one of []
```

Without quotation marks:

```
var query = 
"""
select
...
and ss.status_date < now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - interval :x minute
...
""";
```

The error was:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 205
```

I've also tried different recommendations in this post [Native query with named parameter fails with "Not all named parameters have been set"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829818/native-query-with-named-parameter-fails-with-not-all-named-parameters-have-been)

but without success

Using
Java 17
SpringBoot 2.7.6
PostgreSQL

Comment: What about `searchQuery.setParameter("x", "70");` without quotation marks in query?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass your parameter as string like

```
searchQuery.setParameter("x", "70 minutes");
```

And cast it as PostgreSQL interval type as

```
var query = 
"""
select
...
and ss.status_date < now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - :x::interval
...
""";
```

Comment: I've got:
`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Could not locate named parameter [x], expecting one of [x::interval]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [x], expecting one of [x::interval]`

Comment: What if you separate the parameter from casting `and ss.status_date < now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - :x ::interval`? I've tested it with JDBC and prepared statements and it works on `openjdk 17.0.6 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+10-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.6+10-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)`

Comment: Unfortunately the separation didn't help either. The error was:`
`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"`

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I solved the problem more radically by parameterizing the right operand of `<` entirely:

```
var query = """
...
and ss.status_date < :x
...
""";

var searchQuery = em.createNativeQuery(query, BikeEntity.class);
var calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, - 70);
searchQuery.setParameter("x", calendar.getTime());
return searchQuery.getResultList();
```