Named and indexed parameters do not work in EclipseLink with Spring Boot 3
I'm trying to use EclipseLink as a JPA provider in a Spring Boot 3 app. I seem to be missing something, as Query.setParameter() is not able to set named (:param) or enumerated (?1) parameters. This happens for both native and JPQL queries. However, they do work with the ? style (without a number).
My code is something like this:
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

public List<SomeDto> findBySomeAttr(final String someAttr) {

        // This is actually a longer and more complex query that I have in a sql file.
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE SM WHERE SM.SOME_ATTR = :someAttr";

        Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, "SomeDtoMapping");
        query.setParameter("someAttr", someAttr);

        return query.getResultList();
}

If I try to get the parameter with query.getParameterValue("someAttr"), I get this error:
IllegalArgumentException@133 "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No parameter with name : someAttr was found within the query: DataReadQuery(sql="SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE SM WHERE SM.SOME_ATTR = :someAttr")."

I read something about Query being a proxy instance, but it seems that is not the case for me:
query.getClass()
Class (EJBQueryImpl)@125 "class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl"

It does not work this way either:
@Query(
    value = "SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE SM WHERE SM.SOME_ATTR = :someAttr",
    nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> findTest(@Param("someAttr") String someAttr);

But replacing :someAttr with ?1 does.

Named parameters are not supported in Native (SQL) queries, so :someAttr shouldn't be expected to work. Use JPQL if that is what you are after. Some have stated (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42573540/496099 ) ?someAttr might work, but ?1 is expected to. Maybe show the code and the error you get when you use ?1.

Hi, thanks! It did work for me like this ... ?paramName

JPA Specification:

Only positional parameter binding and positional access to result items may be portably used for native queries


Hi, thanks for your reply! I think things change for JPA implementations like EclipseLink. Because it did work for me like this ... ?paramName (see this answer). I guess for Hibernate it works like this other way ... :paramName (see this answer)
